# How to combine a controller with a listener?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

At my .NET Core HttpPost Controller I get data. This data I pass further for processing. The result about the success of the processing I can get only by setting up a listener. The result I get by the listener I want to return to the user.

**But how can I make the Controller waiting for the listener and handle over the listener return as Controller return?**

Example for illustrative purposes:

```
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatedAsync([FromBody]DataWrapper dataWrapper)
{
    BusinessComponet.CollectData(dataWrapper);
    return returnValueFromListener; // How to do this in real?
}

static void BusinessComponentDeliverResponse(object sender, DeliverEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.IsValid)
        return Ok("received");  // How to use this as return for the controller?
    else
        return BadRequest(e.ErrorMessage); // How to use this as return for the controller?
}
```

The time span until getting the result in the listener will e around 7 seconds right now and I could get it in 1 second with some changes. I think it is ok to let the user wait for the result.

Comment: If I get this right, you are trying to make a long running RPC work over HTTP. What I would do: Server has a Dictionary of keys that reference "ResultState" objects. A Post creates an entry there, and starts processing. Process will update the ResultState object. What you return is a success with a resource-address: which is the result-getting endpoint preconfigured with the key as parameter. Then the client can poll the resultstate. I'd have a finished result removed after some time.

Comment: You're describing how you attempted to solve your problem, not the problem itself. There's no "listener" in ASP.NET Core, unless you mean SignalR. There are no events - they don't even have meaning in a server application. What's the *actual* problem? Start a long-running job and report progress? Pushing notifications to the client is the job of SignalR.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using a listener in .NET Core already at the same application and it works.

Comment: @FrankMehlhop what listener? What you posted is an event handler. Do you mean an HttpListener? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

I will preface this by saying its **a terrible idea** and you should re-architect to avoid doing this...

What you probably actually want to do is for example insert the job in a table or queue, get a service or batch job to process it, and poll for the result using AJAX instead...

That being said, if you insist on doing it this way in the meantime you can just wait for the result like so:

```
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatedAsync([FromBody]DataWrapper dataWrapper)
{
    int timeOut = 0;
    BusinessComponet.CollectData(dataWrapper);
    // Wait for the event handler to fire, with a timeout so it doesn't wait forever
    while (_result == null && timeOut < 20000){
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        timeOut += 1000;
    }
    return _result;
}

private static IHttpResponse _result = null;

static void BusinessComponentDeliverResponse(object sender, DeliverEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.IsValid)
        _result = Ok("received");  
    else
        _result = BadRequest(e.ErrorMessage); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a good and clean solution I changed my methods and are using return values now. So I don't need to use a listener for the response.